# Dot product of two 3 x 11 matrices in matlab is giving a 1x11 matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am doing the dot product of two 3x11 matrices in MATLAB, these matrices are multidimensional but I am only accessing one 'page' at a time. From my maths knowledge I would expect a 3x11 matrix back as result but when using the following code:

```
   contact_force(:,:,k)=dot(km(:,:,k),actual_interf(:,:,k))
```

The answer is in the form of a 1x11 matrix

Comment: Do you really mean http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/dot.html DOT product here, or do you want elementwise multiplication `.*`?

Answer (score 1):

For N-D arrays, [`dot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dot.html) computes the scalar product *along the first non-singleton dimension*. So for two 3x11 arrays, it computes 11 dot products returning scalars, hence a 1x11.

This is the equivalent of:

```
sum(A.*B)
```

If you do not intend to perform the dot product, omit the sum to just get element-wise multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

The dot product of two vectors multiplies each element together, then sums the result to produce one number.

When the `dot()` function in Matlab is called on two 2D matrices, the dot product is computed for *each* set of columns. Thus, for each column you get a scalar result, which is why the answer is returned as 1x11

Answer (score 0):

C = dot(A,B) returns thescalar product of the vectors A and B.
if your matrices are 2D,eg. A and B are m*n matrices, then it will calculate dot product of each columns of A and B. and as you know dot product of two vectors is a single number. thus it will give you an 1 * n vector as resutl;